# Skip with statement in Python if condition is met

Tags: python, with-statement

Consider the following code:

```py
if not condition:
    with my_object.whatever(...) as context_manager:
        do_something()
```

Is it possible to put the checking of `condition` inside `my_object.whatever` such that I don't need to wrap the `with` with an `if` every time? I am looking for an interface like this one:

```py
with my_object.whatever(..., skip_with=condition) as context_manager:
    do_something()
```

but I would not know how to implement this. Maybe rising my own exception inside `__enter__` and then catching it in the `__exit__` ? I don't know if this would be a good practice.

Comment: I don't think so. `__exit__` isn't called if `__enter__` raises. (So you would just be wrapping your `with` statement in a `try` statement instead of an `if` statement.)

Comment: Your current code clearly shows what you mean. Your suggestion doesn't...

Comment: The other difference is that in your current code, neither `my object.whatever` nor the corresponding `__enter__` method gets called; in your suggestion, both do. That's a lot of extra work to relocate a single line of code.

Comment: With the if statement present it is very clear what the flow and conditions of that flow should be, with the syntax change you suggest you are hiding behavior and that in my opinion is bad practice.  FWIW.

Comment: @GeorginaSkibinski thank you for your suggestion, but it does not.